# Python get all possibilities from word's list to create a paragraph

Tags: python, arrays, arraylist, automation

i want a script can generate all possibilities from word's list

example:

array :

```
["Ford", "Volvo", "BMW" ,'word1', 'word2', 'word4','word7', 'word9', 'word5','word100', 'wordaaaaa', 'words'...........etc]
```

to a paragraph contain just 5 words like:

```
word2 word1 Volvo BMW wordaaaaa
words word9 Volvo Ford BMW
word100 word1 Volvo BMW word7
```

and get all possibilities to create a paragraph contain 5 words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

words = ["Ford", "Volvo", "BMW" ,'word1', 'word2', 'word4','word7', 'word9', 'word5','word100', 'wordaaaaa', 'words']

for c in combinations(words, 5):
    print(" ".join(c))
```

Output:

```
Ford Volvo BMW word1 word2
Ford Volvo BMW word1 word4
Ford Volvo BMW word1 word7
Ford Volvo BMW word1 word9
Ford Volvo BMW word1 word5
Ford Volvo BMW word1 word100
Ford Volvo BMW word1 wordaaaaa
...
```

Comment: sir how i can shuffle the array every iteration ?

Comment: you can use [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle). you first have to convert the generator to list: `from random import shuffle` `shuffle(list(combinations(words, 5)))`

Comment: can u please write the code ?

Comment: thank you bro , i try to change combinations(words, 5) to shuffle(list(combinations(words, 5))) but it's not work

Comment: i got this error TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: True! shuffle changes a list *in place* and returns None. You'll have to assign `lst=list(combinations(words, 5))` then `shuffle(lst)`. Then you can loop through `lst`. This is all described in the doc ;-)